# Magento 1.9x paypal - "unable to initialize express checkout" random error

Tags: php, magento, paypal

This issue is like randomly occurring in some of the customers. There is this one customer who experienced the issue where after she placed an order using paypal express checkout and it should go back to the site success order page but it goes to shopping cart page saying "unable to initialize express checkout" and then the cart is empty. This issue occurs to some of users but not all.

I can't seem to track the issue as we tested using paypal sandbox with the same situation with the customer who reported. Logged in, maybe add discount code and then order using paypal express checkout but we can't replicate the error in our numerous test purchase.

Note that most of the customers has no issue occurring to them using paypal express checkout and logged in.

Need help to find the source of issue, or if somebody already experienced this issue and solved it. Thank you!

Comment: you may want to pull the log files and make sure the parameters line up correctly; such as AMT to [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0]; etc

Comment: what if there's only AMT and no [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] at all?

Comment: did you compressed or minified the css?